# How to enable only one ip to squid proxy server?

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm trying to create a simple proxy server with my debian server, I installed squid3 and added that configuration:

```
http_port 3128

forwarded_for off
via off

acl Safe_ports port 1-65535


http_access allow 111.222.333.444
http_access allow Safe_ports
```

But it doest work for the given ip, it only work if I add `http_access allow all`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing the 'type' of record, such as `src` or `dst`.

Try this:

```
acl myhost src 11.22.33.44
http_access allow myhost
```